# shell - Pass command line arguments to bash script does not work

Tags: bash, shell, sh, casperjs, slimerjs

I have a .sh script file and specifically the atguments are not going well, and I do not know the reason --engine = slimerjs and - headless

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e /usr/local/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs --headless /home/user/file.js
```

Comment: What happens and how it differs from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Put the command in quotation marks:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "/usr/local/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs --headless /home/user/file.js"
```